# HTTP '?' link able to use twice?

Tags: html, http, hyperlink, protocols

I have an admin panel which uses the `admin.php?page=X` system to condense all the admin features in to one easy to use page. Although, I also have a Pagination system on the admins 3rd page which also uses the '?' in the link. This doesn't seem to work? The link for instance is:

```
admin.php?page=3?pn=2
```

But, this doesn't show pagination '`2`' this just shows the original page 3 of the admin panel?

Is this because you cannot have more than 1 '?' in a link or is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple querystring parameters are separated by an ampersand `&`:

```
admin.php?page=3&pn=2
```

Comment: So brilliantly simple, didn't understand pagination very much, thanks for the help John!

Comment: Absolutely. You can use as many as you want although there is a limit to how long a query string can be. I *think* it's about 255 characters.